# Handling nested URI's in tastypie

Tags: rest, tastypie

I am building a REST API in which unique objects are owned by users. So URI's need (project requirement) to be formatted like so:

```
/api/v1/user/[user_slug]/book/[book_isbn]
```

example:

```
http://library.edu/api/v1/user/jack@gmail.com/book/1481879707
```

or

```
http://library.edu/api/v1/user/jill@gmail.com/book/1481879707
```

**Both are unique objects**

How do I use tastypie to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write a prepend_urls method in your resource, just as said in this section of Tastypie doc:

[Tastypie Doc - Cookbook#nested-resources](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources)

Instead of Children you'll have your Books resource and you also will change to fit on your URL pattern.